# Finding modulus and argument of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having troubles with finding and argument of these two
$$\frac{1}{i}, \frac{2^{e^{i \theta}}}i $$

for the first one my approach was
$$|z|=\frac{1}ie^0$$
$$e^{i\theta}=e^0$$
$$\theta=0$$
$$|z|=\frac{1}i(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$
I'm stuck here :( 
 for the second one  I've no idea from where to start :(

Comment: $\frac{i}{1}\neq\frac{1}{i}$

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use Euler's identity.
$$e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta+i \sin \theta$$

The first one $\frac{i}{1} = i = e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi)}$

The second is more interesting because of the numerator:

$$2^{e^{i\theta}}= 2^{\cos \theta + i\sin \theta} = 2^{\cos \theta}\cdot 2^{i \sin \theta}$$

It only remains to be put in base $e$, you can do this as follows:

$$2^{i\sin \theta} = e^{\ln(2^{i\sin \theta})} = e^{i\sin \theta \cdot \ln 2}$$

You just need to combine these different steps in order to get the argument.

Comment: could you please elaborate your solution for 1st one, please...

Comment: There are two ways of thinking about it. You could see it geometrically as $i$ is located on the imaginary axis at a distance of 1 from the origin. Meaning an argument of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and modulus of 1. Or using Euler's identity. Because when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ then $\cos \theta = 0$ and $\sin \theta = 1$ meaning $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}} = 0+1\cdot i = i$. Clear?

Comment: in brief:
modulus=$i$
argument=$\frac{\pi}{2}$ right?

Comment: Modulus of $z$ can't be $i$ since modulus is always a real number. The modulus of $i$ would be 1. Where would you place $i$ in the complex plane? What would be the distance between $i$ and the origin?

Comment: sorry, my mistake....
Great help, Thanks :)